# Should I buy an iPod touch in Canada in July or wait 'til September and buy it in Europe?

Tags: ipod-touch

My title is pretty clear: I'm going in Canada for a trip with my father in July and I wonder if I should buy a new iPod touch there or wait until the new one comes out around September and buy in Europe? The 8 GB version costs 199€ (roughly 256 Canadian dollars) in Europe and 199 Canadian dollars in Canada (roughly 154€).

I'm going to use it mainly as a gaming and Internet device. I might listen to music with it from time to time but I won't take the 32 GB version only to have my entire music collection on it.

So, given my use of it, will the new version be worth the extra 45€ (assuming the price won't change)?

Comment: @CajunLuke Thanks for the corrections and sorry for the grammatical mistakes, not my mother tongue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new model (if one comes out; it's not necessarily certain that one will) will be better. Will it be 45€ better? I don't know, and that's something only you can decide. If you don't need the extra disk space, the 8 GB model should be sufficient (despite what @comradsky's answer says, the internals of the 4th-gen touches aren't any different between the size models except the internal storage space.

All in all, I have to say the same thing I always say when it comes to buying Apple products: if you need it, buy it. If you wait, there's always the possibility that they won't release a new model when you thought they would, so you buy the old model, and then they release the new model a month after you thought they would.

Also: consider looking at the [refurbished store](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/specialdeals/ipod) on Apple's website. There are (from time to time) fairly good deals on current- or previous-gen items.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer. But there isn't such 16GB model, is there ?

Comment: @snickers I keep forgetting that iPhone and iPod touch sizes don't match. The smallest touch is 8 GB, then 32 GB. Thanks for catching that; it's now fixed.

Comment: Some may call me an iPod Touch fanboy, but I believe it will be 45€ better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awesome site for recommending when is a good time to buy all Apple products (including iPod Touch)

http://buyersguide.macrumors.com/

Right now the iPod Touch is in "Buy only if you need it mode".   In another month it could be "Don't buy" territory.

I would wait if I were you.

Answer (score -2):

The price won't change. And, yes, it is definitely worth it. You should get the 32 Gig but thats your preference - it has a better CPU. I need to add a picture to my question, but to do that I need 10 reputation.

Comment: Why is it worth it ? Is the new version going to be really better ?

Comment: YEs it will be faster. And will last longer

Comment: okay why has my answer been voted down.

Comment: @comradsky The 32 GB model doesn't have better internals than the 8 GB model. That was the case for the 3rd-generation touches (the 8 GB model was not upgraded from the 2nd generation).

Comment: @comradsky If you add a link to the picture to your question, someone with >10 rep will happily link it for you.

Comment: hey cajun i said i think, theres no need to be rude, he can go to apple.com, its not that difficult

Comment: @comradsky I went to apple.com and it basically said "buy my product anyway, I want to make money". Not exactly the advice I'm looking for if you read my question carefully ;-)